# Enable to load view

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to load view that is in another folder.

where I am load the view that path is as below:

```
         www\payroll\application\modules\shift\controllers\
```

And my view is in below folder:

```
        www\payroll\application\modules\template\views\payroll\inc\
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$this->load->view('template/payroll/inc/view');
```

simple...

Dir: `modules/template/views/payroll/inc/view.php`

Comment: It gives below error:Unable to load the requested file: template/payroll/inc/view/toppart.php

Comment: yes it works, I tested using HMVC, and run. wrong: `template/payroll/inc/view/toppart.php` correct: `template/views/payroll/inc/toppart.php`